# Надо ли и можно запретить доступ к JS файлам?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Хочу узнать надо ли запрещать доступ в Laravel от просмотра JS файлов? Есть уникальный скрипт и хотелось бы скрыть доступ к нему, как это сделать и стоит ли вообще это делать? Не будет ли ругаться система и сотни ошибок?)

Comment: JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента, и его сокрытие или что ещё, не является чем-то что должно вас беспокоить, как клиент выполнит этот js если он не будет ему доступен? Ерунда.... Разве что вы будете его выполнять на сервере при помощи node js...

Comment: Запретить можно, разумеется. Но проще их совсем удалить, если они не нужны.

Comment: Я когда-то попытался зашифровать скрипт, и даже попытался разработать собственный метод обфускации, надеясь, что деобфускатора нигде не будет, кроме, как у меня - [Круговой узор](http://opan.strana.de/u/) Там (см. исходный код страницы) если попытаться скопировать его на другой сайт или хоть как-то изменить исходный код - он работать не будет. Но всё равно у знатоков деобфусцировать его не составило проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Все что отображается на клиенте, в браузере, доступно пользователю и это можно скопировать и сохранить себе на компьютер. Если хотите, чтобы ваш уникальный скрипт нельзя было скопировать, тогда самый верный способ - это вообще не размещать его на сайте.

Многие делают блокировку нажатия нажатия клавиш клавиатуры (F12, CTRL + C, CTRL + U) и мыши, чтобы на сайте никто не смог открыть контекстное меню, инспектор кода, сохранить страницу или скопировать код - и прочие глупости. Но все эти способы обходятся очень легко.

JavaScript файлы, как css можно минимизировать и сжать. Это затруднит какое-либо изменение и использование скрипта.

Если это не просто обычный скрипт, а используется react/vue, то чистые исходники и так уже лежат в какой-нибудь src/resources папочке на сервере, которую никто не может скачать. Ведь в этом случае вы производите импорт и объединение файлов в один или несколько (сборка в бандл) минимизированных и фактически видоизмененных.